# for式のジェネレータ部分にリテラル識別子を使うと、IntelliJの構文チェックツールではエラーだが、実行できる

Tags: scala

## 環境

- Scala 2.12.5
- IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Community Edition)
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10

## 起こったこと

for式のジェネレータ部分に、リテラル識別子を使いました。

```scala
def sampleOpt(i: Int): Option[Int] = Some(i)

val a = for (
  `type` <- sampleOpt(10)
) yield `type` * 2
println("a=" + a) //⇒ a=Sample(20)
```

- IntelliJ IDEAのエディタウィンドウでは、"Cannot resolve symbol `type"というエラーが表示されました。
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
- ビルド＆実行はできました。

## 質問

上記の現象は、何が起こっているのでしょうか？

- IntelliJの構文チェックツールのバグでしょうか？
- Scalaの構文ルールに違反しているのでしょうか？